# How can I work with Twig when using the Display Suite module?

Tags: commerce, display-suite

I am working with Commerce 2 and Display suite, i want to add a field to the presentation that when a product has a boolean field valued to true, do not display a field and display other with twig.
Maybe this way im more clear:
field in product: Variation and a boolean flag
if flag = true dont show the variation "Add to cart" but "Coming soon"

The problem i want to solve is that when i have no stock "add to cart" pass to "out of stock" but i would like to shot "Coming soon" if a flag is true even is i do have stock or not.

Thanks for the time reading this!

Comment: I suggest you check https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields module for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well i manage to do what i asked, i added a new field to product that name is proximamente,i had to let the variation stay but i hide it from view, with a twig field i can show the things in the way i want

twig code:

```
{% set variable = commerce_product.product_id.value%}
{% if commerce_product.field_proximamente.value is null %}
{{ drupal_field('variations','commerce_product',variable,'add_to_cart') }}
{% elseif commerce_product.field_proximamente.value == true %}
<p class="proximamente-btn-view button--add-to-cart button button--primary js-form-submit form-submit is-disabled btn-primary btn">Próximamente</p>
{% else %}
{{ drupal_field('variations','commerce_product',variable,'add_to_cart') }}
{% endif %}
```

i guess is kinda simple but works for me, when the boolean field is true i show the "Próximamente" with all the classes that a variation in Commerce 2 has, the reason of the first " IF " is because i added that new field way later on the product, so some products might not have it enabled so i have to cover that part